# Azure DevOps Branch policy cause Sonar Cloud Error

Tags: azure-devops

We have recently set the below Branch policy to not allow any branch build with errors, to be merged to main:

[image]

We have configured Sonar Cloud as well in the pipeline. When the developer builds their branch its getting successful. But when they merge their PR, its throwing Sonar Cloud authorization. The only change that we have done recently is the updating the branch policy. I am confused why this change is throwing such error which is nothing related to branch policy

Edit:

Just before checking the build error , I am getting this page [image]

Comment: I agree with you. I also don't think that the error is related to the branch policy setting. That error is obviously a certification issue. This problem should come directly from the pipeline itself added in Build Validation, you can try to remove the branch policy, and then manually run the pipeline to see if there are the same errors.

Comment: Sonar authorization issue is coming intermittently. I tested in feature branches and with and without build policy also the issue is coming , but not continuously. Whenever I check the build error page, refresh load content error is showing . i have updated the question with that image

Comment: according to your test, "with and without build policy also the issue is coming", so this issue should not related to the branch policy. And the error image you post, it seems the azure devops service issue.

Comment: Yes you are correct. The issue is not related to branch policy. Issue was with Sonar Service Account password expiry. Thank you, Appreciate your support .

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I added a answer with the info about this ticket, so that can be beneficial to other community members reading the answer, avoid spending a lot of time on a post that already has an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Branch policy cause Sonar Cloud Error

According to the description:

"*When the developer builds their branch its getting successful. But when they merge their PR, its throwing Sonar Cloud authorization. The only change that we have done recently is the updating the branch policy."*

This error message should not related to the branch policy setting, we could remove the branch policy setting to verify it.

Thanks for the `Asterix` sharing:

*The issue is not related to branch policy. Issue was with Sonar Service Account password expiry.*